# Side effects if ViewModel is directly binded to Model of Entity Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, unit-of-work

I have the following problem (high level):
My ViewModel has some properties which can be edited by the user (in my View). Most properties are directly binded to my model of the Entity Framework. In a lot of situations this lead to the problem that I have to detach my model e. g. after saving it to the database (if I don't do it and the user does some changes in the view those changes are reflected automatically when the next `SaveChanges()` is called). Detaching it unfortunately leads to the problem that all virtual properties become null. So I have to make sure that I create proper "copies" of my object before detaching it. This leads to a lot of side effects.

---

To give you a better understanding of my problem some code examples (of course simplified):

My model:

```
public class Child
{
    public int SomeNumber { get; set; }
    public string SomeText { get; set; }
    public int MotherId { get; set; }
    public virtual Mother Mother { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Sibling> Siblings { get; set; }
}
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class ChildViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private IGenericRepository<Child> _repository;

    public string SomeText
    {
        get { return MyModel.SomeText; }
        set
        {
            MyModel.SomeText = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SomeText");
        }
    }

    public Mother Mother
    {
        get { return MyModel.Mother; }
        set
        {
            MyModel.Mother = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Mother");
        }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        if (MyModel.Id == 0)
        {
            Insert();
        }
        else
        {                
            Update();
        }            
        UnitOfWork.Save();
        _repository.Detach(PrimaryModel);
    }
}
```

As you can see the properties of the ViewModel are directly binded to my EF model. In Save I have to detach after saving. If I don't do this this leads to the following problem: A user changes `SomeText` in the View but does not save. Now the `UnitOfWork.Save()` is called. The changed value of `SomeText` is accidentally saved. On side effect of doing so is that the Mother property will now be null.

To avoid this situation I tried to create "real" copies of my object. Therefore every model has to implement a method to copy its values. This becomes difficult and error-prone when talking about complex objects. When trying to save a "copied" object I have even more side effects like the error `Attaching an entity of type ... failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value.` (especially with "copied" 1:many and many:many objects).

---

Summary:

- Directly binding a Model via the ViewModel to the View ...
- ... can lead to some side effects when not detaching it.
- Detaching the model leads to virtual properties which become null.
- To avoid this a copy of the object can be created before detaching.
- It's hard to save copied objects when they are very complex (multiple 1:many and many:many relationships).

This leads to the problem that easy use cases (like "Save data set xyz") - at least they should be easy imo - cost a lot of time and the code becomes more and more complex.

How can I avoid those pitfalls?

Comment: Our solution is that we use the model objects only as pure DTOs. We retrieve them from EF, fill our own objects, and than let them go away. Same for saving. Create new DTOs, attach, fill them and save.

Comment: I thought about the same. This would require an extra layer (service layer or so) which wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: You (we, I'm having the same problem) can also evaluate a mapper that maps from ViewModel to Model (before save). Did you think about it?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple, **do not** create extra properties in your View Model which reference your Model. Instead, **bind directly to the model**.

Here's an example:

```
public string SomeText
{
    get { return MyModel.SomeText; }
    set
    {
        MyModel.SomeText = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SomeText");
    }
}
```

In the code above, you are creating an additional property in your view model, you **do not need to do this**. I'm guessing you are binding to it like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeText}" ... />
```

Instead of creating this extra property, you should bind to the **model**. Like so:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyModel.SomeText}" ... />
```

Now, you won't have to worry about detaching your model anymore.

Comment: I have to do this because the setter in the property of my ViewModel is different to the setter in the Model. In my ViewModel I have to call RaisePropertyChanged, in my model I don't (and there are a few more differences). Further I don't see how this solves all my problems. The point with detach isn't solved this way.